# How to make a lock open after a certain button combination with an Arduino Uno?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am relatively new to the Arduino programming stuff. I have knowledge of the C# language as I use it for my job, I do development with .NET MVC every day. But this language is getting the best of me for some reason. What I want to do is have 5 colored buttons hooked up on a breadboard and into the Arduino, then when the buttons are pressed in a certain combination, it will trigger a servo to unlock a box or something. Can anyone help me out with code snippets that will make this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is what you don't know? How to have 5 buttons on a breadboard? How to read the status of buttons? How to check for the combination? How to trigger a servo? Or other?

Answer (score 0):

First read some [Getting Started with Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage) and make yourself familiar with the Arduino and the electrical components.

Then after a few projects, it will be relative easy, to set up the electronics, and implement the code, for the project.

Go through some [Tutorials](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage).

Watch some of the many, [many videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=arduino+playlists).

Read some of the [books](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=arduino&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Aarduino).